# Formatting Tesseract output to get correct number

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using Tesseract to get textual data from images. In particular, I want to get numbers.

Using Tesseract, I generate a DataFrame with boundind boxes and text (I need both). However, in images most numbers use space as decical sepator. This leads Tesseract to interpret it as numerous different numbers instead of one.

Image Example :
[Number Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgazC.png)

Code Sample:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image = Image.open('../data/number.PNG')
ocr_df = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, output_type='data.frame', lang='fra')
ocr_df.dropna()
```

Output:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK91L.png)

This is a small example, in practice I work with large images with much more text so it's not trivial to concat close numbers.

Is there an easy way to concat them ? Using a Tesseract config for example. Or do I need to manually post-process the numbers to concat them by looking at the bounding boxes ?

Thank you!

Edit : Added code sample.

Comment: It is difficult to envision what you are trying to do without a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Consider adding some code to help us understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the result by upsampling and applying [simple-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

- 1. **Upsampling:** We will upsample the image using [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) and convert it to the gray-scale to make the image easier to process.
- 2. **Simple Thresholding:** Next we will apply [OTSU](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)'s thresholding to make the features easily detected by the tesseract.

---

- Result of OTSU's thresholding

  - [image]
  - ```py
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    ```
- OCR Output:

  - ```
    431 538
    ```

Update-1

---

If you want the output as a single row data-frame, you could do:

- 1. Remove the empty text
- 2. Concatenate the available rows
- 3. Remove the last row

```py
df = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type='data.frame')
df.dropna(subset=["text"], inplace=True)
df["text"] = str(int(df["text"].loc[4])) + " " + str(int(df["text"].loc[5]))
df = df[:-1]
```

Result:

```py
   level  page_num  block_num  par_num  ...  width  height  conf     text
4      5         1          1        1  ...     84      38    95  431 548
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("IgazC.png")

# Up-sample
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

# Convert to gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# OCR
df = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type='data.frame')
df.dropna(subset=["text"], inplace=True)
df["text"] = str(int(df["text"].loc[4])) + " " + str(int(df["text"].loc[5]))
df = df[:-1]
print(df)

# Display
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, this didn't provides the result I want. 

I don't want text.  I want the daframe with bounding boxes and content. The problem is that number like 431 548 are seperated because of the space used as decimal separator. I would like to get only one line in the returned dataframe containing 431 548 not two with 431 and 548. 

I tried your preprocessing and still got two distincts entities for the same number using the example image.

Comment: I understand you are new to programming. What you want is not hard, you could achieve by googling it. Anyway, I've updated mu answer, see the answer below Update-1

Comment: I should have very badbly explained my problem. I have this dataframe. The problem is that I want only one row for 431 548 since it's only one number in my document. You literraly just reproduce the dataframe I put in my question.

Comment: Now  I understand and updated my answer. Please see the answer under Update-1

Comment: It's kind of you to help me but did you read my post ? This is just a toy example. In practice, I have thousands of rows. How can I regroup numbers that goes together and leave apart distinct ones ?